# Find used dateformat (d/m/Y..." and timeformat in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the time zone, the date format (d.m.Y, Y/m/d,...) and the time format (H:i, h:i A,...).

I get the time zone with `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`... But how do I get the other data?

I pass the data to PHP with an `XMLHttpRequest` and want to specify the date and time format there afterwards.

Comment: Why does PHP need to know about the timezone and date format? In backends and databases I would recommend to only work with ISO date strings.

Comment: @JSONDerulo Thank you for your solution.
I use Laravel and Carbon. I don't know the timezone of the visitor in Laravel, so I need to find out the timezone from browser to show the UTC Time in the Timezone from visitor

Comment: In case your date is in a proper format, you can just use the following code to get the formatted date: `new Intl.DateTimeFormat().format(myDate)`, it will take care of the time zone and formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

There is no way to get the date format in your desired output because it's not standardized, but you can use [`formatToParts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) to get the value split up in the different parts:

```js
const parts = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined,
  { dateStyle: 'short', timeStyle: 'short' }
).formatToParts();
console.log(parts);
```

From this you can transform it into your desired format. You may need to change the `dateStyle` or `timeStyle` options.

### Alternative

However, as pointed out in the comments, I would recommend not to deal with time zones and date formats on backend or database side, but rather work there with ISO date strings. To format a date, you can use the [`format`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/format) function:

```js
const myDate = new Date('2023-03-31T09:31:47.362Z');
const intlDateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined,
  { dateStyle: 'short', timeStyle: 'short' });
const formattedDate = intlDateTimeFormat.format(myDate);
console.log(formattedDate);
```